# Explanation of all the different ways to declare higher kinded types in scala

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

I'm trying to understand once and for all the difference between the following type parameter declarations

```
trait T[X] // X could be co/contravariant
trait TSub[X <: AnyRef] extends T[X] // bounded

def m1[T0[A0] <: T[_]]          = ???
def m2[T0[A0] <: T[A0]]         = ???
def m3[A, T0[A0] <: T[A]]       = ???
def m4[A, T0[A0 <: A] <: T[_]]  = ???
def m5[A, T0[A0 <: A] <: T[A]]  = ???
def m6[A, T0[A0 <: A] <: T[A0]] = ???
```

I know I can bound `T0`'s type parameter (`T0[_ <: SomeType] <: T[?]`) so that only subtypes of `T` with stricter bounds are accepted.

What I don't get is how the parameter of the "right hand side" affects the outcome, i.e. the difference between `m1`/`m3` and `m2` and between `m4`, `m5` and `m6`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I spent some time on it and understood what happens (I guess). Here's my analysis:

```
trait Y

trait T[X]
trait TSub[X <: Y] extends T[X] // bounded

trait TCo[+X]
trait TCoSub[+X <: Y] extends TCo[X] // bounded

trait TContra[-X]
trait TContraSub[-X <: Y] extends TContra[X] // bounded


def m1[T0[_] <: T[_]] = ???
m1[T]
//  m1[TSub] -> not accepted because of stricter bounds

def m1Co[T0[_] <: TCo[_]] = ???
m1Co[TCo]
//  m1Co[TCoSub] -> not accepted because of stricter bounds

def m1Contra[T0[_] <: TContra[_]] = ???
m1Contra[TContra]
//  m1Contra[TContraSub] -> not accepted because of stricter bounds


def m2[T0[A0] <: T[A0]] = ???
m2[T]
//  m2[TSub] -> not accepted because of stricter bounds

def m2Co[T0[A0] <: TCo[A0]] = ???
m2Co[TCo]
//  m2Co[TCoSub] -> not accepted because of stricter bounds

def m2Contra[T0[A0] <: T[A0]] = ???
//  m2Contra[TContra] -> contravariant type is not accepted because for any A0 T0[A0] >: T[A0] instead of <:
//  m2Contra[TContraSub] -> not accepted because of stricter bounds



def m3[A, T0[_] <: T[A]] = ???
// m3[Y, T] -> doesn't conform, T0[X] should be a subtype of T[Y] for every X.
// m3[Y, TSub] -> not accepted because of stricter bounds

def m3Co[A, T0[_] <: TCo[A]] = ???
// m3Co[Y, TCo] -> doesn't conform, T0[X] should be a subtype of TCo[Y] for every X.
// m3Co[Y, TCoSub] -> not accepted because of stricter bounds

def m3Contra[A, T0[_] <: TContra[A]] = ???
// m3Contra[Y, TContra] -> doesn't conform, T0[X] should be a subtype of TContra[Y] for every X.
// m3Contra[Y, TContraSub]-> not accepted because of stricter bounds


def m4[A, T0[_ <: A] <: T[_]] = ???
m4[Y, T] // Ok, wider bound
m4[Y, TSub] // Ok, wider bound

def m4Co[A, T0[_ <: A] <: TCo[_]] = ???
m4Co[Y, TCo] // Ok, wider bound
m4Co[Y, TCoSub] // Ok, wider bound

def m4Contra[A, T0[_ <: A] <: TContra[_]] = ???
m4Contra[Y, TContra] // Ok, wider bound
m4Contra[Y, TContraSub] // Ok, wider bound


def m5[A, T0[_ <: A] <: T[A]] = ???
// m5[Y, T] -> Wider bound but doesn't conform: T0[X <: Y] should be a subtype of T[Y] for every X but T0 is invariant
// m5[Y, TSub] -> Same bound but doesn't conform: T0[X <: Y] should be a subtype of T[Y] for every X but T0 is invariant

def m5Co[A, T0[_ <: A] <: TCo[A]] = ???
// m5Co[Y, TCo] -> doesn't conform: T0[X] should be a subtype of Tco[Y] for every X but T0 bound is larger
m5Co[Y, TCoSub] // Same bound/conforms because being T covariant T0[X] is a subtype of Tco[Y] for every X  because X is bounded <: Y

def m5Contra[A, T0[_ <: A] <: TContra[A]] = ???
// m5Contra[Y, TContra] -> Wider bound but doesn't conform: T0[X] should be a subtype of T[Y] for every X, but X is contravariant
// m5Contra[Y, TContraSub] -> Same bound but doesn't conform: T0[X] should be a subtype of T[Y] for every X, but X is contravariant


def m6[A, T0[A0 <: A] <: T[A0]] = ???
m6[Y, T] // bound ok, conforms because T0[X <: Y] is a subclass of T0[X] for every X (it's actually the same)
m6[Y, TSub] // bound ok, conforms because T0[X <: Y] is a subclass of T0[X] for every X (it's actually the same)

def m6Co[A, T0[A0 <: A] <: TCo[A0]] = ???
m6Co[Y, TCo] // bound ok, conforms because T0[X <: Y] is a subclass of T0[X] for every X (it's actually the same)
m6Co[Y, TCoSub] // bound ok, conforms because T0[X <: Y] is a subclass of T0[X] for every X (it's actually the same)

def m6Contra[A, T0[A0 <: A] <: TContra[A0]] = ???
m6Contra[Y, TContra] // bound ok, conforms because T0[X <: Y] is a subclass of T0[X] for every X (it's actually the same)
m6Contra[Y, TContraSub] // bound ok, conforms because T0[X <: Y] is a subclass of T0[X] for every X (it's actually the same)
```